# Stopping an app's icon from showing on dock even when running

Tags: dock, icon

I'm currently using a Mac for work and there are certain apps that I like to keep running but I don't want the icon to show up on the dock.

I've tried many ways to fix this, but the icon always ends up showing. I've also unchecked the "show recent applications on dock" in the System Preferences, but that still shows the icon when the app is running.

Is there any way that I can stop the icon from appearing at all?

Thanks.

Answer (score -3):

Open System preferences → Dock & Menu Bar → Enable → **Show indicators for open applications**

[image: Show indicators for open applications]

Comment: That only hides the *indicator* that says the app is currently running or not. It doesn't hide the **icon** itself.